# Browser not interpreting &quot character used in string built in JS

Tags: javascript, html

Why does the following not appear in the browser correctly i.e. why doesn't the browser interpret the `&quot;`s as quotes and instead doesn't do anything with them.

```
foo += &quot; + value + &quot; + ',';
```

`foo` is a string that gets iteratively built.

Many thanks :).

Comment: What happens instead? Where is this code located, in a HTML page or a JS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&quot;` is an HTML entity and has nothing to do with JavaScript. If you build `foo = "&quot;" + value + "&quot;"` and then assign `element.innerHTML = foo;` (e.g. `element` is a `<div>`) then the element's text will be `"value"`.

Comment: On a side note, `&quot;` is an invalid JavaScript construct, it should be enclosed in quotes/apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `&#8220;` (Left Double Quote) and `&#8221;` (Right Double Quote)

```
var foo = '&#8220;' + value + '&#8221;,'
$('#myDiv').html(foo);
```

will render as “dave”, (of course if `value = "dave"` )

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for  is:

```
var foo+='"value",';
```

if you want to store "value" in foo.
IF you specifically want to store "
use

```
var foo='&quot;value&quot;,'
```

&quot; is text not a variable